# Add JS function to one page checkout before payment.save()

Tags: magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout, javascript

In the one page checkout I have a javascript function that I need to run before `payment.save();` is called when you click on the continue button. My function (which is included in the page code) uses a 3rd party library to generate a token that is injected into the form which is then submitted with payment.save().

Is there a way to add a javascript function before `payment.save()` fires after clicking on the continue button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the save method, of the core payment object, with your own.
This will then allow you to run your own code first, and then continue on (or completely bypass) the core save method.

I use this for exactly the same reason as you seem to want it for. 
I have a module that needs to inject a token from a gateway into the form, and use that token as the posted cc number to magento payment controller (instead of the actual cc number).

The trick is to make sure the custom js is loaded *after* the core payment object was defined, so it can wrap it.
To get that right, I include this bit of code in the credit card form template of my module (`ccform.phtml`)  This simply injects my js file (called pinpayments.js) into the page header, ensuring it is after the core payment object is define (which happens in opcheckout.js)

[ side note: I really dislike how onepage checkout loads opcheckout.js via a script tag in the file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` - it just seems dirty ]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  var header_already_added = false;
  for (var i=0; i< x.length; i++){
      if (x[i].src == "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/pinpayments.js') ?>"){
             header_already_added = true;
      }
  }

  if (header_already_added == false){
    // add header if not already added
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/pinpayments.js') ?>';
    head.appendChild(s);
  }
//]]>   
</script>
```

in pinpayments.js, I the wrap the required core method with my own, with the ability to continue back to the core save method. [ The code has been adjusted, striping out non relevant parts, but you should get the idea ]

```
Payment.prototype.save = Payment.prototype.save.wrap(function(save) {
                var validator = new Validation(this.form);
                if (this.validate() && validator.validate()) {
                    // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO BEFORE SAVE
                    save(); // THIS WILL CALL CORE SAVE THAT WAS WRAPPED
                }
        });
```

You can see some other ways to extend core js in this excellent blog entry:

http://erfanimani.com/four-ways-to-edit-magentos-javascript/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use a ajax function to inject javascript onto a page before a certain functionality call.

Although why don't you just include it in the page outright?

Comment: The code is being included on the page, the issue is that I cannot call my functionality when the continue button is clicked but before the payment.save() method is fired

Comment: Have the button call the function and put the payment.save() function call at the end of this initial function.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have currently but the button is coded into the main template so don't really want to require that change

Comment: Create your own template then and define whatever functionality you want.