# Generating token with using payment form data

Tags: checkout, payment, payment-gateway

I have a module that needs to inject a token from [2Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/) payment gateway into the form, and use that token to authorize and place order.

I've my custom checkout module, in which 2checkout is enabled with form to enter card info. During checkout, the card authorization is failed because token is created for card validation.

[2Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/) is using [2co.js](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/create-token) JavaScript library to generate tokens.

I've added a js file to get payment info and generate token from it. Code is like this which works fine with default Magento checkout .

```
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        if( typeof( document.getElementById('payment_form_twocheckout') ) !== 'undefined' ) {
            TCO.loadPubKey(TcoEnv);

            IWD.OPC.savePayment = IWD.OPC.savePayment.wrap(
        function(callOriginal) {
  // remaining code to get payment arguments and generate token
```

I've added js files in customcheckout handle.

```
<customcheckout_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="twocheckout.script" template="twocheckout/script.phtml"/>
            <action method="addJs"><file>twocheckout/2co.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>twocheckout/paymentCustomForm.js</file></action>
        </reference>
</customcheckout_index_index>
```

When I'm navigating to customcheckout page now, I'm getting error in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: IWD is not defined

due to the line of code `IWD.OPC.savePayment = IWD.OPC.savePayment.wrap(`

What I should use instead of `IWD.OPC.savePayment = IWD.OPC.savePayment.wrap(` to wrap it. 
As, proxiblue  suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52689/add-js-function-to-one-page-checkout-before-payment-save), I think my Js file is being loaded before core payment object was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please include IWD js with your custom checkout handle.